# How to read a pdf using WebView in Android Studio using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, pdf-reader

I have tried multiple times to read a pdf using `WebView` but it only displays a blank screen. What should I do?
Here is my code:
MainActivity.kt

```
      class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                view?.loadUrl(url.toString())
                return true
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl("https://mindorks.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/courses/MindOrks_Android_Online_Professional_Course-Syllabus.pdf")
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android WebViews do not support viewing PDFs. Some older Android devices aren't even shipped with the ability to view PDFs and rely on the user downloading an application from the Play Store in order to do so. You'll likely need to download the PDF via its URL through some sort of client (I'd recommend Retrofit) as a steam or byte array. From there, you'll need to launch an implicit intent with the Uri set to the PDF's data and the type set to the "application/pdf" media type. Once downloaded, please use the [Android Sharesheet](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-system-sharesheet) to query for any acceptable applications. There are open source libraries which can aid in this process. But, I had this exact use case at a previous position, and I ended up implementing as described.